# how to remove URL in tweet if there is url like "pic.twitter.com"

Tags: python-3.x

i want remove url like "pic.twitter.com/zzzzz" how to remove it ?

i have tried to remove urls, this is the code

```py
def remove_urls(vTEXT):
vTEXT = re.sub(r'(https|http|pic)?:\/\/(\w|\.|\/|\?|\=|\&|\%)*\b', '', vTEXT, flags=re.MULTILINE)
return(vTEXT)

hihi = remove_urls("this picture is belongs to pic.twitter.com, an te page is https://skype.co.id")
print(hihi)

# the result
this picture is belongs to pic.twitter.com, an te page is
```

so, i want the result is this picture us belongs to and the page is

Answer (score -1):

```
txt = 'Hello all please help pic.twitter.com/dgfdbf sdde'

' '.join(word for word in txt.split(' ') if not word.startswith('pic.twitter.com/'))
```

Comment: This would only remove `pic.twitter.com/` but not other links.